# How does the 8 million legally belong to Byrde?

Tags: plot-explanation, ozark

In the pilot of *Ozark*, we learn that Marty's partner Bruce scammed high ranked cartel member Del and stole 8 million dollars.

Del spares Marty's life in exchange of the retribution of the 8 million, and Marty laundering for him.

In 48 hours, Marty manages somehow to get the hand on the 8 million (probably in Bruce's secret account?), and simply withdraw the cash from the bank like it was his own personal and legal money to hand it to Del.

How did he do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Because it was his money

There's no indication he accessed Bruce's accounts. He liquidates his **own assets**.

> Only after Wendy tries to empty some bank accounts on her own and nearly loses her life when the cartel finds out, does she understand how desperate things are. As Marty and Wendy hustle to **liquidate every last cent of their assets**....
>
> <sup>[Denver Post](http://www.denverpost.com/2017/07/20/ozark-netflix-review/)</sup>

When he talks to the bank to arrange the withdrawal he's asked..

> Your entire portfolio?
>
> Ten percent penalty for early withdrawal, plus another 32% in taxes.

Comment: I wasn't aware he was that rich... for a financial advisor.

Comment: @SilverBebs: But he wasn't just any ordinary financial advisor. He had been laundering money for a drug cartel for at least several years and had been getting paid well for it.